# "Object reference not set to an instance of an Object" during SharePoint Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search

I have the following Alternate Access Mappings 
Internal URL :            zone                 Public URL 
http://spappsrv           Default                 
http://url.home.com       extranet                http://url.home.com

My Server 
Server 1 -> WFE server (Search host controller and search query service turnedoff)
Server 2 -> Application Server (Search host on but Web Foundation Service off)
Server 3 -> Database Server

All the Search Topology is hosted in Server2

When searching from the default zone URL spappsrv, the search results are fine.
If search is initiated from other zones , there is error in the search results as below : 
"Unknown error" - Object reference not set to an instance of an object .

The log gives the following detail error :

> at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.ExtractMapping(Pair`2 properties, SPSite site, IDictionary`2 urlMapping, IDictionary`2 reverseUrlMapping)
>
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetNewCacheEntry(Pair`2 properties)
>    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetUrlMapping(QueryProperties properties)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)
>
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b__14()
>
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)

Original error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.ExtractMapping(Pair`2 properties, SPSite site, IDictionary`2 urlMapping, IDictionary`2 reverseUrlMapping)

 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetNewCacheEntry(Pair`2 properties)
 at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetUrlMapping(QueryProperties properties)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)

 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b__14()

 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)

Comment: Are you crawling the default zone?

Comment: Yes I am crawling the default zone.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Are you using a custom Display Template?

Comment: SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise. I am not sure about us using a custom Display Template, however everything is in the default settings and we have not modified any templates related to search. They should be in the default settings.

Comment: Have you tried checking the status of your whole Search Service Application using the SharePoint Search Health Reports (SRx)? You can get them here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SRx-Core-SharePoint-Search-d60113e9